# PHP file_get_contents sending big POST

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have following method to send `file_get_contents` requests:

```
protected function query($page, $post, $timeout = false, $debug = false, $enableWarnings = true) {
    $this->correctHostIfNeeded(self::HTTP_CONNECTION_TYPE);
    $page = $this->host . (substr($page, 0, 1) == '?' ? '' : '?') . $page;
    $opts = array('http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ));
    if (!empty($post)) {
        $postdata = http_build_query($post);
        $opts['http']['content'] = $postdata;
    }
    if ($timeout > 0)
        $opts['http']['timeout'] = $timeout;
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = $enableWarnings ? file_get_contents($page, false, $context) : @file_get_contents($page, false, $context);
    return $result;
}
```

It usually works fine, better than curl version (it occasionally not executing properly, regardless of data in post). Unfortunately, if I send really big POST usign `file_get_contents` (for example array with 100k elements) it fails. Sometimes the target server saves part of the data but it never gets it all.

I know the internet connetion between servers is not the problem (both servers are in my own datacenters and speed between is stable about 100Mb). Also the code itself on both servers seems to be fine because with smaller data it works fine and if I change to `curl` big packages are received properly (unfortunately it sometimes fails and I read that it's not to strange behavior for curl).

Answer (score 1):

Increase the execution time of the page, write this at the top-

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Comment: You may have a point. I don't want to check it at daytime so I cannot tell if that's the case now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read file by parts, and merge result afterwards. In file_get_context you can specify offset and max_length argument.

Comment: I think his problem is with sending data, not reading the response.